# What's the right way to clear a bytes.Buffer in golang?

Tags: go, buffer

I'm trying to clear a `bytes.Buffer`, but there's no such function in the document

Maybe I should just renew the buffer? What's the right way to do it?

```
buffer   = bytes.NewBufferString("")
buffer.Grow (30000)
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

> [Package bytes](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/)
>
> func (*Buffer) Reset
>
> ```
> func (b *Buffer) Reset()
> ```
>
> Reset resets the buffer so it has no content. b.Reset() is the same as
>   b.Truncate(0).
>
> func (*Buffer) Truncate
>
> ```
> func (b *Buffer) Truncate(n int)
> ```
>
> Truncate discards all but the first n unread bytes from the buffer. It
>   panics if n is negative or greater than the length of the buffer.

```
buffer.Reset()
```

Comment: @warl0ck Keep in mind that this is effectively like doing `b = b[:0]`, it doesn't actually "free" the internal buffer.

Comment: @OneOfOne, so how would one actually clear the underlying array?

Comment: Clear or free? @DmytroTitov

Comment: “Free”, I guess.

Comment: How can I release the memory of the buffer ?

Comment: Go's GC will reclaim once the variable is not referenced any more.